# How to iterate through an Array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I'm a real noob for react. (Come from a java background lol). I've been struggling with trying to render an array of objects from the cryptocompare api. The api looks like this using console.log(data.Data)

> 0: {CoinInfo: {…}, RAW: {…}, DISPLAY: {…}}
>
> > 1:
> > CoinInfo:
> > Algorithm: "Ethash"
> > AssetLaunchDate: "2015-07-30"
> > BlockNumber: 11354985
> > BlockReward: 2.2818216676269
> > BlockTime: 13.133262903712646
> > DocumentType: "Webpagecoinp"
> > FullName: "Ethereum"
> > Id: "7605"
> > ImageUrl: "/media/20646/eth_logo.png"
> > Internal: "ETH"
> > MaxSupply: -1
> > **Name**: "ETH"
> > NetHashesPerSecond: 301850977727331
> > ProofType: "PoW"

so on and so forth. I am trying to render for now specifically the name of the coin.

My code is as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      names: []

    };
  }

  async getData() {
    const response = await axios.get(endpoint)
    const data = response.data;
    console.log(data.Data[0].CoinInfo.Name)
    this.setState({

      names: data.Data
    })
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getData();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.names.map((name, i) => {

          <div key={i}>
            <li>
              // Not sure what to put here....
              {name[i]}
            </li>
          </div>
        })}
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Now I've been playing around with it for a couple of hours to no avail. I keep getting blank screens or uncaught reference. If someone can point me in the right direction that would be awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this section here:

```
 <div>
        {this.state.names.map((name, i) => {

          <div key={i}>
            <li>
              // Not sure what to put here....
              {name[i]}
            </li>
          </div>
        })}
      </div>
```

You should checkout how the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function works in the first place. Instead of **name**, you should name the individual element inside your array (each coin). So it's gonna become something like this:

```
<div>
    {this.state.names.map((coin, i) => {

      <div key={i}>
        <li>
          
          {coin.name}
        </li>
      </div>
    })}
  </div>
```

where **name** is just a attribute of the json object **coin**. Does this make sense?

Comment: thanks for your response, I just tried it, and I am still getting a blank screen, could this be because I am not accessing the array correctly? Or possibly using the key incorrectly?

Comment: maybe because you are accessing the key incorrectly. In the example I've provided **coin** is your entire json object, you need to use different attributes of this object to display it. These are just examples but you should inspect your object, it'll look something like this `{coin.name}` or `{coin.value}`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I wasn't using the keyword this. I solved it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to return something from your map callback:

```
{
 this.state.names.map((name, i) => {
   return (
     <div key={i}>
       <li>
         // Not sure what to put here....
         {name[i]}
      </li>
     </div>
   )
 })
}
```

or you can use another variant:

```
this.state.names.map((name, i) => (
  <div>...</div>
)
```

The second one - your `name` is the object `{CoinInfo: {…}, RAW: {…}, DISPLAY: {…}}`
So if you want to put a name inside `li` just get it as you do above: `name.CoinInfo.Name`.

```
{
 this.state.names.map((name, i) => {
   return (
     <div key={i}>
       {name.CoinInfo.Name}
     </div>
   )
 })
}
```

If you don't sure about `name` just console log this inside your callback before return JSX.

BTW you don't need to use `await this.getData()` just `this.getData()` and don't make `componentDidMount()` async. And don't use `<li>` tag without  - or just put name inside `div` without `<li>`

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was able to solve it, turns out I needed this keyword